# How am I supposed to have a sprite look like it is collecting a coin, and have that coin reset position, along with adding points?

Tags: javascript, code.org

So I am basically trying to do a lesson for my class in STEM. This level I encountered on code.org has really made me go insane. Basically, I am making a game in the game lab. The bunny sprite on the bottom moves left and right to pick up coins, while the coins drop down onto the bunny sprite, almost like a shower. I basically need to have the score go up by a certain amount of points, have the coin sprite reset itself ( the coordinates, ) and I need an answer. If anyone has an answer, please help me! Thank you.
-Soraahh
     PS. I will receive messages via email.